# Count distinct no of paying users

Tags: mysql, sql

This is my input table (tab) with userid and 'verified purchase'. (Users can try purchasing, but may decide not to. Hence verified purchase)

```
UserID   Verified_Purchase
 1001          T
 1001          T 
 1001          F   
 1002          T 
 1002          T
 1003          F
 1004          T
 1004          F


My expected output is to find out the no of unique buyers / non buyers. 
No of Buyers :  3  (1001,1002,1004)
No of Non Buyers : 1 (only 1003)
```

What I have tried:

```
select distinct UserID from tab
WHERE Verified_Purchase = 'T'

select distinct UserID from tab
WHERE Verified_Purchase = 'F'
```

But these are not giving the correct answers as few users are being double counted.

Please let me know how I can proceed with the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, summarize by userId, then aggregate:

```
select is_verified, count(*) as num_users
from (select UserId, max( Verified_Purchase = 'T' ) as is_verified
      from tab t
      group by UserId
     ) t
group by is_verified;
```